# Python executes else statement for no reason

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a function where the user gives a number from 1-7, and that number that corresponds to a day in the week, otherwise there will be a message saying: 'Sorry this is not the right number'

My Code So Far:

```
def num_day():

user_number = int(input('Please enter a number between 1 & 7: '))

if user_number == 1:
    print('The number 1 corresponds to Monday')

if user_number == 2:
    print('The number 2 corresponds to Tuesday')

if user_number == 3:
    print('The number 3 corresponds to Tuesday')

if user_number == 4:
    print('The number 4 corresponds to Tuesday')

if user_number == 5:
    print('The number 5 corresponds to Tuesday')

if user_number == 6:
    print('The number 6 corresponds to Tuesday')

if user_number == 7:
    print('The number 7 corresponds to Tuesday')

else:
    print('Sorry, that is not a valid number.')


num_day()
```

It gets the if statement correct, but keeps on throwing in 'Sorry, that is not a valid number'

Comment: You want `if...elif...else` not separate `if` clauses.

Comment: Yes, the `else` applies only to the most recent `if`, not to the whole stack.

Comment: Why do all the numbers from 2 to 7 correspond to Tuesday? Your code says to print `'Sorry, that is not a valid number.'` whenever `user_number` isn't 7.

Comment: ...which is to say, this is behaving correctly-as-written if it prints "Sorry, that is not a valid number." for every value except 7.

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat absurd. Python's else statements are not counterexamples to the principle of sufficient reason (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_sufficient_reason)

Comment: BTW, this can be done much more compactly if you use a tuple or list of weekday names, but maybe you haven't learned about those yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this fails because each `if` is its own logical statement. You want to use `if..elif..else` instead of `if..if..else`.

```
if user_number == 1:
    print('The number 1 corresponds to Monday')

elif user_number == 2:
    print('The number 2 corresponds to Tuesday')

elif user_number == 3:
    print('The number 3 corresponds to Tuesday')

elif user_number == 4:
    print('The number 4 corresponds to Tuesday')

elif user_number == 5:
    print('The number 5 corresponds to Tuesday')

elif user_number == 6:
    print('The number 6 corresponds to Tuesday')

elif user_number == 7:
    print('The number 7 corresponds to Tuesday')

else:
    print('Sorry, that is not a valid number.')
```

This combines them all into one logical statement, and the `else` is then the catch-all for ALL the tests, not just the last one.

---

That said, a bit of over-engineering is always fun for beginner questions like this. How would you feel about an `Enum` for a weekday data structure?

```
import enum

class Weekday(enum.Enum):
    MONDAY = 1
    TUESDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 3
    THURSDAY = 4
    FRIDAY = 5
    SATURDAY = 6
    SUNDAY = 7

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()

user_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
try:
    weekday = Weekday(user_number)
    print(f"The number {user_number} corresponds to {weekday}")
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid number.")
```

Comment: Thank you, and that data structure seems a tad bit scary to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
user_number = int(input('Please enter a number between 1 & 7: '))
DayDict = {1:'Monday',2:'Tuesday',3:'Wednsday',4:'Thursday',5:'Friday',6:'Saturday',7:'Sunday'}

def num_day(x):
     if x in DayDict:
         print 'The number '+ str(x) + ' corresponds to '  + DayDict[x]
     else:
         print 'Sorry, that is not a valid number.'

num_day(user_number)
```

Comment: I wouldn't, I'd use an Enum. Or for a less-overbuilt solution, I'd use a list with the first element `None`. `[None, "Monday", "Tuesday", ...]`

Comment: I downvoted because the answer you provided is a typo'd Python2 drop-in replacement for OP's code (which isn't even accurate per his question, though presumably 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 weren't all supposed to be Tuesday...) with no mention of why his code wasn't working as expected.